# What is the difference between 'return item' and 'return true' in JavaScript array methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript

First of all, my apologies for any mistakes in my question as I have very less idea about asking questions.

I came up with these two cases :-

```
const comment = comments.find(function (comment) {
            if (comment.id === 823423) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And this:-

```
const comment = comments.find(function (comment) {
            if (comment.id === 823423) {
                return comment;
            }
        });
```

What's the difference between the two as I tried to run both the code and it gave the same result and which one is a better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) callback is expected to return a boolean flag (a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value), where a truthy value means the item is what you're looking for. So semantically, `return true` is correct. (Although `return comment` works because any non-`null` object reference is truthy, it's misleading.)

Some other methods (for instance, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) expect the callback to return something other than a boolean flag. The `map` method expects you to return the item that should be in the resulting mapped array; `sort` expects a number (where negative, zero, and positive values tell `sort` the relative ordering of the elements the callback is passed for comparison). Whenever you're not sure what the callback should return, check the MDN documentation (or any good reference).

---

In your specific example, you're relying on implicitly returning `undefined` when the ID doesn't match (because in that case, the callback never explicitly returns a value). Instead, you should explicitly return a falsy value. The simplest way is to just directly return the result of the comparison:

```
const comment = comments.find(function (comment) {
    return comment.id === 823423;
});
```

Or more concisely, by way of parameter destructuring and an arrow function:

```
const comment = comments.find(({id}) => id === 823423);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better.

The second one will be implictly cast to `true` like the first one. By the way, you should also add `return false` to both.

You should try typescript, it can helps you to write better code.